# Live Graphical Demonstation of a Breadth-First Search Algorithm

Tags: java, pathfinding, javafx

As a first step to making a PacMan clone, I wrote a Breadth-First Search demonstration that updates itself live as you draw walls and drag around the start and end points. It was inspired by [the site that I learned the algorithm through](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html), which has similar demonstrations.

A sample of it:

[image]

To use it, use the mouse to drag the start (black) and end (pink) points, or draw on empty space to draw a wall.

### My Main Concerns:

- This is my first crack at a pathfinding algorithm, so I'm sure there is room for improvement. Any tips here would be appreciated!
- Allowing canvas elements to be dragged was more painful than I though it'd be. I opted to use a global `enum` member to track what's currently being held, but it feels like a hack. Is there a more standard way of moving non-node elements?
- Anything else that you think could be improved upon

### A Couple Things to Note:

- This demo is fairly rough around the edges. Attempting to draw out-of-bounds fails silently in the application, but results in a `NoSuchElement` exception being thrown behind the scenes.
- The demo code uses a `Wall` class, but it currently doesn't do anything. Since the application only cares about what cells are occupied and assumes that any occupied cell is a wall, the private member `wall` can be replaced by any type (A number type for example), and it will still work fine.

FrontierVisual.java:

```
package pacmanTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import utils.Duple;
import utils.MainLoop;

/**
 * To record what's currently being dragged
 */
enum DragPoint {
    START, GOAL, NONE
}

public class FrontierVisual
        extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;

    private final int areaWidth = 800;
    private final int areaHeight = 800;

    private final double drawScale = 20;

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800, 800);
    private GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    private final Area<Wall> area = new Area<>(areaWidth, areaHeight);
    private final Pathfinder<Wall> pathFinder = new Pathfinder<>(area);

    private Duple<Integer> startPos = new Duple<Integer>(10, 10);
    private Duple<Integer> goalPos = new Duple<Integer>(30, 30);

    private List<Duple<Integer>> path = new ArrayList<>();

    private DragPoint dragging = DragPoint.NONE;

    private final Wall wall = new SolidWall();

    private void drawSquare(Duple<Integer> position, Color color) {
        gc.setFill(color);
        gc.fillRect(position.getX() * drawScale, position.getY() * drawScale, drawScale, drawScale);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

        BorderPane rootNode = new BorderPane();

        scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        rootNode.setCenter(canvas);
        canvas.setOnMousePressed(dragStartHandler);
        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(dragContHandler);
        canvas.setOnMouseReleased(dragStopHandler);

        MainLoop mainLoop = new MainLoop(10000000, t -> {
            utils.Utils.clearCanvas(gc);

            gc.setFont(Font.font(20));
            gc.fillText(dragging.toString(), 10, 30);


            List<Duple<Integer>> path = pathFinder.findPathFromAToB(startPos, goalPos);

            path.stream()
                .forEach( pathPos -> drawSquare(pathPos, Color.BLUE) );

            area.forallNonEmptyCells( (pos, w) -> drawSquare(pos, Color.CHOCOLATE) );

            drawSquare(startPos, Color.BLACK);
            drawSquare(goalPos, Color.PLUM);
        });

        mainLoop.start();

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //Handle the mouse being pressed
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragStartHandler = event -> {
        double x = event.getX() / drawScale;
        double y = event.getY() / drawScale;

        //The amount off the square you can press and still shift focus to the start/goal point
        double dragRadius = 2;

        if (pointIsInCircle(x, y, startPos.getX(), startPos.getY(), dragRadius)) {
            dragging = DragPoint.START;

        } else if (pointIsInCircle(x, y, goalPos.getX(), goalPos.getY(), dragRadius)) {
            dragging = DragPoint.GOAL;

        } else {
            dragging = DragPoint.NONE;
        }

        System.out.println("Drag Started - Dragging: " + dragging.toString());
    };

    //Handle the mouse continuing to be dragged
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragContHandler = event -> {
        int x = (int)(event.getX() / drawScale);
        int y = (int)(event.getY() / drawScale);

        Duple<Integer> newPos = new Duple<Integer>(x, y);

        switch (dragging) {
            case START:
                startPos = newPos;
                break;

            case GOAL:
                goalPos = newPos;
                break;

            case NONE:
                area.setCellAt(x, y, wall); 
                break;
        }
    };

    //Handle the mouse being released
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragStopHandler = event -> {
        dragging = DragPoint.NONE;
    };

    private static boolean pointIsInCircle(double x, double y, double centreX, double centreY, double radius) {
        double  xDiff = x - centreX,
                yDiff = y - centreY;

        return xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff <= radius*radius;
    }
}
```

Pathfinder.java:

```
package pacmanTest;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import utils.Duple;

public class Pathfinder<T> {

    //To track walls
    Area<T> area;

    public Pathfinder(Area<T> a) {
        area = a;
    }

    /**
     * Preset offsets representing each of the four directions.
     */
    private static final List<Duple<Integer>> fourDirectionOffsets = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        new Duple<Integer>(1,0), new Duple<Integer>(-1,0), new Duple<Integer>(0,1), new Duple<Integer>(0,-1) ));

    /**
     * Finds a path from aStart to bGoal, taking into consideration walls
     * 
     * @param aStart The start position
     * @param bGoal The goal position
     * @return A list representing the path from the start to the goal
     */
    public List<Duple<Integer>> findPathFromAToB(Duple<Integer> aStart, Duple<Integer> bGoal) {
        Deque<Duple<Integer>> frontier = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Map<Duple<Integer>, Duple<Integer>> cameFrom = new HashMap<>();

        frontier.push(aStart);

        while (!frontier.isEmpty()) {
            Duple<Integer> current = frontier.pop();

            if (current.equals(bGoal)) break;

            List<Duple<Integer>> neighbors = cellsAround(current, fourDirectionOffsets);

            neighbors.stream()
                .filter(location -> !cameFrom.containsKey(location) && area.cellIsInBounds(location) && area.getCellAt(location) == null)
                .forEach( neighbor -> {
                    frontier.add(neighbor);
                    cameFrom.put(neighbor, current);

                });

        }

        return reconstructPath(cameFrom, aStart, bGoal);
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a backtracking map into a path
     * 
     * @param cameFrom Backtracking map
     * @param start Start position
     * @param goal Goal position
     * @return A list representing the path from the start to the goal
     */
    private static List<Duple<Integer>> reconstructPath(Map<Duple<Integer>, Duple<Integer>> cameFrom, Duple<Integer> start, Duple<Integer> goal) {
        List<Duple<Integer>> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(goal);

        Duple<Integer> current = goal;

        do {
            path.add(current);

            current = cameFrom.get(current);

        } while (current != null && !current.equals(start));

        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the cells surrounding pos as indicated by the given offsets
     * @param pos The position to find the surrounding cells of
     * @param offsets Positions relative to pos to check
     * @return
     */
    private static List<Duple<Integer>> cellsAround(Duple<Integer> pos, List<Duple<Integer>> offsets) {
        List<Duple<Integer>> surroundingCells = new ArrayList<>();

        offsets.stream()
            .map( offset -> pos.map(offset, (x1, x2) -> x1 + x2) )
            .forEach(surroundingCells::add);

        return surroundingCells;
    }
}
```

Duple.java:

```
package utils;

import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

/**
 * A simple immutable Duple class where both members are the same type
 * 
 * @author Brendon
 *
 * @param <T> The type of its members
 */
public class Duple<T> {

    private final T xPos;
    private final T yPos;

    public Duple(T x, T y) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }

    public T getX() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public T getY() {
        return yPos;
    }

    /**
     * Applies the function to each member of the Duple
     * @param f The function to apply to each member
     * @return The resulting Position
     */
    public Duple<T> map(UnaryOperator<T> f) {
        return new Duple<T>(f.apply(xPos), f.apply(yPos)); 
    }

    /**
     * Applies the function to this and the other Position
     * @param otherPos The other Position to use
     * @param f A function taking 2 Positions, where the first parameter is a member of this, and the second is a member of otherPos
     * @return The resulting Position
     */
    public Duple<T> map(Duple<T> otherPos, BinaryOperator<T> f) {
        return new Duple<T>(f.apply(xPos, otherPos.xPos), f.apply(yPos, otherPos.yPos)); 
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((xPos == null) ? 0 : xPos.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((yPos == null) ? 0 : yPos.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Duple other = (Duple) obj;
        if (xPos == null) {
            if (other.xPos != null) return false;
        } else if (!xPos.equals(other.xPos)) return false;
        if (yPos == null) {
            if (other.yPos != null) return false;
        } else if (!yPos.equals(other.yPos)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")";
    }

}
```

MainLoop.java:

```
package utils;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

/**
 * An extension of an {@link AnimationTimer} that allows the user to select their framerate.<p>
 * 
 * Also allows for a more convenient syntax to declare the main loop routine
 * 
 * @author Brendon
 *
 */
public class MainLoop extends AnimationTimer {

    private final long updateGraphicsEvery;

    private final Consumer<Long> doEveryUpdate;

    private long lastTime = IDEALFRAMERATENS;

    /**
     * @param updateEveryNS How often to run the loop.
     * @param f The main-loop body. Its parameter is the number of nanoseconds since the last update.
     */
    public MainLoop(long updateEveryNS, Consumer<Long> f) {
        this.updateGraphicsEvery = updateEveryNS;
        doEveryUpdate = f;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long currentTime) {

        long nanosElapsed = currentTime - lastTime;

        if (nanosElapsed < updateGraphicsEvery) {
            return;

        } else {
            lastTime = currentTime;
            doEveryUpdate.accept(nanosElapsed);

        }

    }

    public final static long NANOSPERSECOND = 1000000000;
    public final static long IDEALFRAMERATENS = (long)(1 / 60.0 * NANOSPERSECOND);

}
```

Utils.java:

```
package utils;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class Utils {
    private Utils() {

    }

    /**
     * Clears the canvas associated with the given {@link GraphicsContext}
     * 
     * @param gc The associated GraphicsConetext to clear
     */
    public static void clearCanvas(GraphicsContext gc) {
        Canvas c = gc.getCanvas();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    }

}
```

Comment: A minor matter of terminology: your pathfinding algorithm is not A* but rather a BFS (breadth-first search). However, I believe that in your use cases BFS is enough.

Comment: @coderodde Oh. I'm just following the guide on A*. They might be just opening with BFS as an introduction. Thanks, I'll update the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Separate Model from Rendering

The `FrontierVisual` class contains at least two semantically distinct groups of fields:

1. Visual component related properties, like `stage`, `scene`, `areaWidth`, `areaHeight` and `drawScale`.
2. Virtual space definition, like `area`, `pathFinder`, `startPos` etc.

They should be separated. All JavaFx-related stuff would remain in `FrontierVisual` class and the model would be better described within a dedicated entity. For small applications like this one, there is probably no need to implement fully the [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, but at least model-view separation would be beneficial, bringing more flexibility and extensibility.

#### Don't Abuse of Generics

Please look closer at these declarations:

```
Map<Duple<Integer>, Duple<Integer>> cameFrom = ...
List<Duple<Integer>> path = ...
```

Do you find this *pollution* with generics, spread everywhere in the code, useful, readable and aesthetically pleasant?

I guess that what you are trying to do here is to anticipate a probable future replacement of `Integer`s with `Double`s and so on.

*Update*. To reduce this overflow of generics, that may be useful to transform `Duple<T>` into an abstract class and add a short one that inherits from it with the right numeric type. But I doubt that this is necessary at all. Your virtual space is better defined using integers. Why not just have a `Point` class with `int x, y`? That will avoid boxing/unboxing with `Integer` in many cases.

Similar changes may be done with the other generics used... Genericity is good, of course, but it should be pondered if it's really necessary here.

#### Consider Using Existing API

The `Duple<T>` class seems to have a number of features similar to [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) or [`javafx.geometry.Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html). They may be considered for reuse here.

p.s. Please change package names to something that respects Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you. I've never used the MVC pattern before. Maybe this'll be a good start point to try it. And I'm using a generic Duple because I'm using the same class for all my projects, and most use `Double`, but you're right, it ends up taking up a lot of extra space. I wish Java had type synonyms. I really don't like the idea of rewriting the entire class just to change the types; to me that almost defeats the purpose of generics in the first place. I didn't know about the existing `Point` classes, so I'll probably switch to them; I'm sure they have more functionality.

Comment: And what do you mean my package names don't respect Java conventions? I though the only requirement was that they start with a lower case.